# How to open folder using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How to open a project from file explorer using Android Studio,

For visual-studio-code we can open by `code .` in the address bar or command prompt. Is there any shortcut like this for opening in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can achieve it by creating Command-line Launcher

1. Press OK in Popup window
2. open terminal
3. type: studio your-project-folder
4. press enter

Then Android Studio will open your project.